# Swift 2.0 and Parse - 'init()' is unavailable: use 'init(domain:code:userInfo:)'

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, nserror

after upgrading to swift 2.0 and going through a bunch of errors I ended up with this error which I do not know how to solve:

`init()` is unavailable: use `init(domain:code:userInfo:)`

Here is the code:

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
 self.actInd.startAnimating()
    for var i = 0; i < (objects!.count); i++ { 
     let countObject = (objects?[i] as! PFObject)
      print( (countObject.objectId)! )
     let queryT = PFQuery(className:"Transactions")
      queryT.whereKey("eventID", equalTo:(countObject.objectId)!)
      print( queryT.countObjects() )
      self.countedEvents.append(countEvents(objectId: (countObject.objectId)!, count:  queryT.countObjects() ))
    print( (countObject.objectId)! )

    self.actInd.stopAnimating()
}
super.objectsDidLoad(NSError())
}
```

The error appears here -   super.objectsDidLoad(NSError())

Thanks, 
Stuart

Answer (score 5):

ok, as per the Apple documentation this works:

super.objectsDidLoad(NSError(domain: NSURLErrorDomain, code: NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile, userInfo: nil))